Do studies exist that keep complete track of protein loss and ingestion?
I've been recently eating about 180 grams of protein a day. I've started wondering if that is excessive.
Are there any studies that completely track protein input and output (stool, urine, skin shedding etc.)?
Given estimates that human body loses ~15 grams of protein a day, it feels too optimistic that 165 grams would just be attached to my body in a day. I would assume, if my body is not in some extreme anabolic state, that I would just excrete all of it out even more.

What's your understanding of how the body digests and utilizes protein? The protein you eat doesn't "attach" to anything.

Protein I eat is broken down into smaller amino acids, at some point probaboy all the way to the essential amino acids, sometimes oxidized into energy molecules.
Point of my question is that there's loss of amino acids through sweat, urine, stool. This loss seems very small. Body is efficient in reusing amino acids. RDA is big, recommendation for athletes is bigger. Why is that if protein turnover is no where near the recommendations.
